# Can you translate these 2 examples from Functional Languages 101 ? (Scheme -> Clojure)

Tags: clojure, scheme

Got these examples I would like to understand but they are in Scheme. I would like them in Clojure :D

**Example 1** - counting the length of a list

```
(define length
  (lambda (ll)
    (cond
      ((null? ll) 0)
      (#t (add1
        (length (cdr ll)))))))
```

**Exemple 2** - square each element of a list

```
(define squares
  (lambda (li)
    (cond
      ((null? li) ())
      (#t (cons
            (* (char li) (char li))
            (squares(cdr
    li)))))))
```

**Example 3** - the "map" function (as in map/reduce)

```
(define map (lambda (func lst)
  (cond ((null? lst) ())
        (#t (cons (func (car lst))
              (map func (cdr lst)))))))
```

**Curried "map"**

```
(define map2
  (lambda (func)
    (lambda (lst)
      (cond ((null? lst) ())
        (#t (cons (func (car lst))
              ((map2 func) (cdr lst)))))))
```

**Motivation**

The examples are from a presentation on Functional Programming someone else might be interested it: [Functional Languages 101: What’s All the Fuss About?](http://www.dzone.com/links/r/functional_languages_101_whats_all_the_fuss_about.html)

*Once you submit an answer, I'd like your agreement to post it as a comment at that presentation for Clojure people to understand the original code*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Length of a list:

```
(defn my-length [lst]
    (loop [len 0 x lst]
        (if (empty? x)
            len
            (recur (+ 1 len) (rest x)))))

user=> (my-length '(1))
1
user=> (my-length '(1 2 3 4))
4
user=> (my-length '())
0
```

Square each element of a list:

```
(defn squares [lst]
    (loop [sqrs '() x lst]
       (if (empty? x)
           (reverse sqrs)
           (recur (cons (* (first x) (first x)) sqrs) (rest x)))))

user=> (squares '(1 2 3 4))
(1 4 9 16)
```

Map:

```
(defn my-map [func lst]
    (loop [res '() x lst]
       (if (empty? x) 
           (reverse res) 
           (recur (cons (func (first x)) res) (rest x)))))

user=> (my-map (fn [x] (* x 2)) '(1 2 3))
(2 4 6)
```

Map2:

See nickik's solution.

Answer (score 6):

I have some stoff here: http://github.com/nickik/Essentials-of-PLs-in-Clojure/blob/master/src/EssentialsOfProgrammingLanguages/core.clj

Its all scheme to clojure stuff. You can download the source of the Essentials of Programming Languages-Book to have the Scheme code.

---

Here are your examples:

```
(defn length [lst]
    (cond
      (seq ll) 0
      :else (inc (length (rest lst))))))
```

Note: clojure has a count function

---

```
(defn squares1 [li]
   (cond (nil? (seq li)) (empty li)
     :else (conj (squares1 (rest li)) (* (first li) (first li)))))

(defn squares2 [li]
   (map #(* % %)  li))
```

---

```
(defn mymap [f coll]
        (cond (nil? (seq coll)) (empty coll)
          :else (conj (mymap f (rest coll)) (f (first coll)))))
```

---

```
(defn map2 [f]
    (fn [lst]
        (cond (nil? (seq lst)) (empty lst)
              :else (conj ((map2 f) (rest lst)) (f (first lst))))))
```

Note you can not just make a 1:1 translation. The diffrence between how '() evals and so on.

Here are the most importend ones

- (nil? (seq list))  not  (null? lst) because '() is not nil in clojure
- conj is better then cons you can make the function work with mure datastructures
- (empty lst) is better then '() because (empty lst) keeps the type vector, list, record, structs or something else

Answer (score 2):

And more clojurey translation of `map`:

```
(defn map
  [f coll]
  (lazy-seq
    (when-let [s (seq coll)]
      (cons (f (first s)) (map f (rest s))))))
```

Exploit closures: define `map-inner` like `map` above.

```
(defn map
  [f]
  (fn [coll]
    (map-inner f coll)))
```

In idiomatic clojure normally you exploit that the nil is logical false.

```
(defn length
  [coll]
  (loop [s   (seq coll)
         len 0]
    (if s
      (recur (next s) (inc len))
      len)))
```

As with `map`: you would use lazy sequences instead of eager lists.

```
(defn squares
  [coll]
  (lazy-seq
    (when-let [s (seq coll)]
      (let [fst (first s)]
        (cons (* fst fst) (squares (rest s)))))))
```

Answer (score 0):

`define` is `def` in clojure, `lambda` is `fn`, function arguments are written as vectors `[]`, not lists `()`, `null?` is `empty`, `car` is `first`, `cdr` is `rest` and the default case for `cond` is specified with `:else`, not `#t`.

So for your first example we get:

```
(def length
  (fn [ll]
    (cond
      (empty? ll) 0
      :else (+ 1 (length (rest ll))))))
```

This can be written a little more succinctly using `defn` instead of `def` and `fn`, but the same is true for the scheme version, so I chose the way that is the closest to the original.

The other examples can be translated the same way.

Comment: @Belun: That's just a name. `lambda (func lst)` is a lambda taking two arguments named `func` and `lst`. The clojure equivalent is `fn [func lst]`.

Comment: @sepp2k> here's a challenge for you: can you create and use a macro for example 1 and 2 ? :P

Comment: @nickik: Neither is the scheme version. As I said, I gave the version that is most similar to the original.

Comment: @sepp2k> yes, 1 macro that gets some parameters and then can build those 2 functions